# Django Form - Selection dependent on another field

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating application to manage home budget. I've got a few models - Date, Expense, Category, Income.

It looks like this

```
class Date(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='date')

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    date = models.ForeignKey(Date, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='date', default='Styczeń 2022')

class Expense(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="account")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expense')
    date = models.ForeignKey(Date, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Styczeń 2022')

class Income(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="account_income")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='income')
```

How can I make the category selection dependent on the date in ExpenseForm? Each category has its own date. I need to display categories only for the selected date in the expense form.

This is because the user does not know which category to select if they have several of the same one. For example, "Food" for "January 2022", "February 2022" and "March 2022".

This is how my ExpenseForm looks now:

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ('name', 'amount', 'category', 'account', 'date',)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=user.category.all())
        self.fields['account'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=user.account.all())
        self.fields['date'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=user.date.all())
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 border border-2 border-transparent border-gray-200 focus:outline-none rounded-none !focus:border-red-700'})
        self.fields['amount'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 border border-2 border-transparent border-gray-200 focus:outline-none rounded-none !focus:border-red-700'})
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 border border-2 border-transparent border-gray-200 focus:outline-none rounded-none !focus:border-red-700'})
        self.fields['account'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 border border-2 border-transparent border-gray-200 focus:outline-none rounded-none !focus:border-red-700'})
        self.fields['date'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 border border-2 border-transparent border-gray-200 focus:outline-none rounded-none !focus:border-red-700'})

        self.fields['name'].label = 'Nazwa'
        self.fields['amount'].label = 'Kwota'
        self.fields['category'].label = 'Kategoria'
        self.fields['account'].label = 'Konto bankowe'
        self.fields['date'].label = 'Zakres dat'
```

Have you got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Each time you select a `Date`, you must make an ajax request and update the options of the `Category` select. You can do all that or use a plugin that does it automatically for you like: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html#chained-select2. This is not the only one, there are plenty other plugins that do the same thing.